# What are my options to pull configuration files from Google Cloud Storage to App Engine Standard?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need to read .php files in a bucket that is in Google Cloud Storage inside of my App Engine (standard) instance(s).

I have two web applications:

- Web App 1 is an internal tool (hosted on-premise) that allows us to change some configurations and saves it to a local .php file in JSON form, and then is rsync'd to Google Cloud Storage.
- Web App 2 is another internal tool that is hosted on App Engine (Standard - php72). This app needs to constantly read the configuration files from Web App 1.

We have a few other web applications that also depend on these configuration files, but since they are not related to this particular problem I won't explain them.

The way we currently solve this problem is by running a cron on Web App 2 every minute that rsync's from Google Cloud Storage to the server.

Some options I have come up with:

- Stream the configuration files from the bucket to Web App 2

  - https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-storage/v1.12.2/storage/readme
- Cloud Storage Fuse, but I'll have to figure out a way to reload PHP

  - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse
- Switch to App Engine (Flex), create a custom docker image that has gcloud installed and credentials to the bucket. Problem is with this option is our production environment would be different then our staging environment

Comment: Let me see if i understood correctly: You have two apps. App 1 updates some files that are rsync-ed to Google Cloud Storage.  App 2 (PHP72) has to read those files from the Cloud Storage. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mayeru That is correct. App Engine Standard doesn't have the gcloud tool so be able to use the `gcloud rsync` command.
I think my best option is to switch staging and production to App Engine Flex :(

Comment: If you want to "rsync" the files from the filesystem on your App2 instance that would be a simple option, in case you want to keep the App Engine standard env, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A way to access your Cloud Storage from App 2, whenever there's an update on your Cloud Storage, would be:

1. Create an endpoint on your app that would initiate the reading process of the files. Since you will be inside PHP, use the [PHP Cloud Storage libs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-php).

import the lib:

```
composer require google/cloud-storage
```

General code to [download Cloud Storage objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample):

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

/**
 * Download an object from Cloud Storage and save it as a local file.
 *
 * @param string $bucketName the name of your Google Cloud bucket.
 * @param string $objectName the name of your Google Cloud object.
 * @param string $destination the local destination to save the encrypted object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function download_object($bucketName, $objectName, $destination)
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->object($objectName);
    $object->downloadToFile($destination);
    printf('Downloaded gs://%s/%s to %s' . PHP_EOL,
        $bucketName, $objectName, basename($destination));
}
```

2. Create a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#cloud-storage-example) that would run on background and gets activated when an update is performed on Cloud Storage (Triggered by Cloud Storage), you can specify if the event is caused due to some object being: created, deleted, archived or updated (metadata update), but have in mind that you will have to create the script using Go, Nodejs or Python.

The script would be a call to your endpoint on App 2:

```
import requests

def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    url = 'https://app2.appspot.com/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f"call made.")
    print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")
```

Remember to add "requests" dependency on the "requirements.txt" tab from Cloud Console Functions GUI.

You can make this interaction as simple or complicate as you wish, the advantage is the "syncing" only occurs when changes on the Cloud Storage bucket happens and not every minute like you are doing currently with the Cron job.

Comment: There is one thing that needs to be clarified and that I believe the OP has overlooked. An App Engine Instance is not guaranteed to be a single instance. In reality, you can have as many instances as needed based on load and on settings in the app yaml. Unless he sets the max instances to one, a cron job or cloud function will trigger only one instance and not all the instances. The OP needs to provide more information about the nature of these configuration files in its GAE case and find a proper mechanism to update all its instances.

Comment: That is true, but I don't think OP is actually writing into the instance's local filesystem, because according to the documentation that's not possible: "In App Engine, the local filesystem that your application is deployed to is not writeable. This behavior ensures the security and scalability of your application." -> https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/  . @Michael Delle If my solution doesn't solve your issue could you elaborate a little bit more on what App 2 has to do with the files? If you can share the Cron job script that you are using it would help.